# Access LightDM configuration in KDE system settings (Kubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, lightdm

I'm running Kubuntu 16.04 and use LightDM (not SDDM).

In a previous version of Kubuntu it was possible to access the LightDM configuration (e.g. changing background,...) via the KDE system settings. I cannot find this option in Kubuntu 16.04. Is it still possible somehow?

The documentation of the package `lightdm-kde-greeter` states "This package also includes a KCM module to configure the greeter.". Is this related to the System Settings GUI?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the configuration file directly, but you may have to install lightdm-gtk-greeter (if not already installed).  Go to the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

Then edit the configuration file:

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
```

or if you prefer to use a GUI text editor,

```
sudo -i kate /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
```

If you want to edit the background wallpaper specifically, search for the line that begins with `background=` and replace the text which follows with the path to your file.  I would recommend copying your file into `/usr/share/wallpapers` and pointing to that path.

Comment: Thanks! A similar approach works with the `lightdm-kde-greeter` which I worked out previously. However,  I am explicitly looking for the GUI configuration via the System Settings in KDE.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, KConfig Modules are what you would use to add features to the KDE control panel ([here](https://github.com/KDE/sddm-kcm) for example the one for SDDM).

And one [existed](https://marc.info/?l=kde-core-devel&m=134564698803343&w=2) as [a part](https://github.com/KDE/lightdm/tree/master/kcm) of the lightdm-kde-greeter. But considering your experience, I suppose that did never work with Plasma 5 since it always remained [stuck](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115453/kde-and-lightdm-on-archlinux/#577597) to Qt4 libraries.